# Calculate cost of several items with tax and a discount

Tags: vb.net

Can anyone help with this school task I have

The task is to ask the user for items and the cost of the items until they chose to stop. Then combine all the costs and take 20% VAT and 10% off from 2 randomly selected items.

Here is the code I have so far (I have 2 buttons and a listbox)

```
Public Class Form1
    Dim CurrentA As Integer

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As System.Object, e As System.EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click
        Dim Items(CurrentA) As String
        Dim Coins(CurrentA) As Single
        Dim Stay As String

        CurrentA = 0
        Do Until CurrentA = 20
            Items(CurrentA) = InputBox("Please Enter The Item")
            Coins(CurrentA) = InputBox("Please Enter The Cost Of The Item")
            Stay = InputBox("Type Yes If More Items or Type No if no More")
            Stay = Stay.ToLower

            If Stay = "yes" Then

            End If

            If Stay = "no" Then
                Exit Do
            End If

            ListBox1.Items.Add(Items(CurrentA) & " " & Coins(CurrentA))
            CurrentA += 1
        Loop
    End Sub
End Class
```

Comment: You didn't ask a question.

Comment: Please turn on Option Strict. 
You can find this setting in 
Tools Menu -> Options -> Projects and Solutions -> VB Defaults.
This will save you from bugs at runtime.

Answer (score 0):

First, a few comments on the code you presented.

```
Dim CurrentA As Integer
'An Integers default value is zero, I don't see why this is a class level variable
'always declare variables with as narrow a scope as possible
Private Sub Button3_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button3.Click
    Dim Items(CurrentA) As String 'Declares an Array of Type String with an Upper Bound of 0
    'Upper Bound is the highest index in the array
    'Arrays start with index 0
    'So your array will have 1 element at index 0
    Dim Coins(CurrentA) As Single
    Dim Stay As String
    CurrentA = 0 'unnecessary because the default of CurrentA is already 0, but OK for clarity because it could have been changed elsewhere
    'This is behaving like a console application with the code repeating in a loop.
    'In Windows Forms it would be more likely to do this in a button click event (btnAddItem)
    Do Until CurrentA = 20
        'On the first iteration CurrentA = 0
        'On the second iteration CurrentA = 1 - this exceeds the size of your array
        'and will cause an index out of range error
        Items(CurrentA) = InputBox("Please Enter The Item")
        'With Option Strict on you must change the input to a Single
        Coins(CurrentA) = CSng(InputBox("Please Enter The Cost Of The Item"))
        Stay = InputBox("Type Yes If More Items or Type No if no More")
        Stay = Stay.ToLower 'Good! The user might no follow directions exactly
        If Stay = "yes" Then
            'This is kind of silly because it does nothing
        End If
        'Lets say I say no on the first iteration
        'This avoids the index out of range error but
        'nothing is added to the list because you Exit the loop
        'before adding the item to the ListBox
        If Stay = "no" Then
            Exit Do
        End If
        ListBox2.Items.Add(Items(CurrentA) & " " & Coins(CurrentA))
        CurrentA += 1
    Loop
End Sub
```

We could use arrays but not knowing how many items will be added means either making the array bigger than needed or using Redim Preserve on every addition. A much better choice is a List(Of T). They work a bit like arrays but we can just add items without the ReDim stuff.

```
Private lstCost As New List(Of Single)
Private Sub Button4_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button4.Click
    'Pretend this button is called btnAdd, and you have 2 test boxes
    lstCost.Add(CSng(TextBox2.Text))
    'The $ introduces an interpolated string. It is a step up form String.Format
    ListBox2.Items.Add($"{TextBox1.Text} - {CSng(TextBox2.Text):C}") 'The C stands for currency
    TextBox1.Clear()
    TextBox2.Clear()
End Sub

Private Sub Button2_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button2.Click
    'Pretend this button is called btnTotal
    'Dim total As Single = (From cost In lstCost
    '                       Select cost).Sum
    Dim total As Single = lstCost.Sum
    Label1.Text = total.ToString("C") 'C for Currency
End Sub
```